# Match when text is equals to something xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

What I'm trying to do is really simple, but I can't seem to get it working.

I have the following xml:

```
<analysis>
    <field>
        <name>field_1</name>
        <type>number</type>
        <tag>Number Field Number One</tag>
    </field>
    <field>
        <name>field_2</name>
        <type>text</type>
        <tag>Text Field Number One</tag>
    </field>
    <field>
        <name>field_3</name>
        <cell>A12</cell>
        <type>Excel</type>
        <tag>Value that comes from an Excel file</tag>
    </field>
</analysis>
```

I want that XML to output this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th> // Name in spanish
            <th>Tipo</th>   // Type in spanish
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Number Field Number One</td>
            <td>Número</td>  // Number in spanish
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Text Field Number One</td>
            <td>Campo de Texto</td>  // Text field in spanish
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value that comes from an Excel file</td>
            <td>Excel (A12)</td>  // Excel (cell)
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My transformation so far is the next:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="analysis">

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Tipo</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="field[type != 'table']"/>
                <!-- I have another type called table which I'm ignoring for this question and won't follow the same scheme -->
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <br />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="campo[field != 'table']">

        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="tag" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="type"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </xsl:template>

    <!-- The following templates don't match -->

    <xsl:template select="type = 'Excel'">
        <xsl:param name="cell" select="preceding-sibling::node()/cell" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Excel ', $cell)" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template select="type = 'number'">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Número'" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template select="type = 'text'">
        <xsl:value-of select="'Campo de Texto'" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As the code says, the last templates don't match. How do I match a tag when its text is equals to something? My output is what I want, but with 'number', 'text' and 'Excel' values instead of their equivalents in spanish, which is what I want.

I've tried other things like `<xsl:template select="field[type = 'Excel']">`, but same result.

Answer (score 3):

> "How do I match a tag when its text is equals to something?"

Focusing on the specific problem of *matching an element when it's text equals specific value*, you can use `.` which references current context element to accomplish that 'matching' task, for example :

```
<xsl:template match="type[.='text']">
    <xsl:value-of select="'Campo de Texto'" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="*:analysis">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Tipo</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*:field">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="tag"/></td>
      <td><xsl:apply-templates select="*:type"/><xsl:apply-templates select="*:cell"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*:type[text()='text']">Campo de Texto</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*:type[text()='number']">Número</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*:type[text()='Excel']">Excel</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*:cell">&#32;(<xsl:value-of select="."/>)</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hey cad, need help with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69207608/xslt-masking-data-conditional-on-other-tags