# XSLT - masking data - Conditional on other tags

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to mask an xml document where some specific tags are present. I have created a java app which contains `saxon9he` as dependency.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>saxon9he</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have multiple use case, some are straight forward but some are conditional. Assuming the below given `<Prsn>` tag is present at multiple different locations:

### Input xml snippet

```html
<ns3:Prsn>
  <ns3:FrstNm>BDMFN</ns3:FrstNm>
  <ns3:Nm>BDMSN</ns3:Nm>
  <ns3:BirthDt>2000-01-02</ns3:BirthDt>
  <ns3:Othr>
    <ns3:Id>GB1592102</ns3:Id>
    <ns3:SchmeNm>
      <ns3:Cd>CCPT</ns3:Cd>
    </ns3:SchmeNm>
  </ns3:Othr>
</ns3:Prsn>
```

### Transformation that is needed

In this above provided XML, we have some tags [**FrstNm**, **Nm**, **BirthDt**] which we need to mask (remove the actual data from these tags and replace with # for each character), which by the way I have achieved so far.

##### Need Help

Tricky part is when we have tag `<Othr><SchmeNm><Cd>` which can have values [**NIND, CCPT, CONCAT**], we need to mask `<Othr><id>`, but any other value in `<Othr><SchmeNm><Cd>` apart from NIND, CCPT, CONCAT then no change in `<Othr><id>`.

### Transformation.xsl

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='FrstNm']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(text(), '[A-Za-z]','#')" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Nm']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(text(), '[A-Za-z]','#')" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='BirthDt']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(text(), '[0-9]','#')" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The `replace()` function does not exist in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Saxon 9.4 is a long time ago: the current version is 10.5

Comment: With Saxon you can use the XSLT 2.0 syntax `match="*:Nm"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do regex-based search and replace, the minimum XSLT version you need is XSLT 2.0.

Also, don't use `local-name()`. Register a prefix for the namespace URI and use that. The prefix does not have to match the XML document, as long as the namespace URI is the same.

Input:

```
<ns3:Prsn xmlns:ns3="some-namespace-uri">
  <ns3:FrstNm>BDMFN</ns3:FrstNm>
  <ns3:Nm>BDMSN</ns3:Nm>
  <ns3:BirthDt>2000-01-02</ns3:BirthDt>
  <ns3:Othr>
    <ns3:Id>GB1592102</ns3:Id>
    <ns3:SchmeNm>
      <ns3:Cd>CCPT</ns3:Cd>
    </ns3:SchmeNm>
  </ns3:Othr>
</ns3:Prsn>
```

XSLT 2.0+:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:person="some-namespace-uri"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="person:FrstNm|person:Nm|person:BirthDt">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(text(), '[A-Za-z0-9]', '#')" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<ns3:Prsn xmlns:ns3="some-namespace-uri">
  <ns3:FrstNm>#####</ns3:FrstNm>
  <ns3:Nm>#####</ns3:Nm>
  <ns3:BirthDt>####-##-##</ns3:BirthDt>
  <ns3:Othr>
      <ns3:Id>GB1592102</ns3:Id>
      <ns3:SchmeNm>
         <ns3:Cd>CCPT</ns3:Cd>
      </ns3:SchmeNm>
  </ns3:Othr>
</ns3:Prsn>
```

If you only have XSLT 1.0 available, you can use `translate()`. But that requires that you either explicitly list *all* possible input characters:

```
<xsl:template match="person:FrstNm|person:Nm|person:BirthDt">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="tanslate(
      text(),
      'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-add-everything-else',
      '##################################################################################'
    )" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or that you settle on something simpler:

```
<xsl:template match="person:FrstNm|person:Nm|person:BirthDt">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text>[redacted]</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

> Tricky part is when we have tag `<Othr><SchmeNm><Cd>` which can have values [NIND, CCPT, CONCAT], we need to mask `<Othr><id>`, but any other value in `<Othr><SchmeNm><Cd>` apart from NIND, CCPT, CONCAT then no change in `<Othr><id>`.

That's easy. in XSLT 1.0+ this works:

```
<xsl:template match="
  person:FrstNm|person:Nm|person:BirthDt|person:Id[
    ../person:SchmeNm/person:Cd = 'NIND' or 
    ../person:SchmeNm/person:Cd = 'CCPT' or
    ../person:SchmeNm/person:Cd = 'CONCAT'
  ]
">
```

or even this:

```
<xsl:template match="
  person:FrstNm|person:Nm|person:BirthDt|person:Id[
    contains('|NIND|CCPT|CONCAT|', concat('|', ../person:SchmeNm/person:Cd, '|'))
  ]
">
```

In XSLT 2.0+ you can use sequences:

```
<xsl:template match="
  person:FrstNm|person:Nm|person:BirthDt|person:Id[
    ../person:SchmeNm/person:Cd = ('NIND', 'CCPT', 'CONCAT')
  ]
">
```

Comment: I wanted to mask <Othr><id> on the basis of <Othr><SchmeNm><cd> if value is NIND or CCPT or CONCAT.

Comment: @truekiller See update.

Comment: @truekiller Also consider something better than `[a-zA-Z0-9]` for the regex approach. `\w` works well and covers all Unicode letters and numbers.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68407659/3016153